# Chameleon i18n and pluralization

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, chameleon

How does pluralization in Chameleon templates?

I didn't manage to find examples in the documentation.

For, example could be having output

```
 <span>1 car</span>


 and

 <span>2 cars</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chameleon takes its i18n syntax from Zope pagetemplates, which does unfortunately not support pluralization.

Comment: Any hints what's the best practice duing pluralization then? Calling gettext() from the page template using Python?

Comment: It will depend on your environment. Nothing in the Pyramid or ZTK stack really supports it. If you are using stdlib gettext (or possibly the Babel wrappers) you could call dngettext manually.